# Como fazer um web scraping em um site com aspx usando python

Tags: python, asp.net, post, web-scraping, python-requests

Estou tentando fazer um scraping de uma página que usa aspx. A questão é que quando vou em inspecionar elemento os dados que preciso estão lá, porém quando dou o requests na página vem tudo do html, menos a parte dos dados que preciso. Esses dados ficam no meio do html entre um "Grid de OC", e só essa parte é cortada. Acredito que deva ser algo nos parâmetros do POST, mas estou iniciando no scraping e travei nisso. Qualquer ajuda vai ser muito bem vida. Desde já agradeço!

```
import os
import io
import re
import sys
import json
import boto3
import os.path
import requests
import zipfile
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from python3_anticaptcha import ImageToTextTask


with requests.Session() as session:

    url = 'https://www.bec.sp.gov.br/bec_pregao_UI/_Imagens/imagem_aleatoria.aspx'
    url_acesso = f'https://www.bec.sp.gov.br/bec_pregao_UI/OC/pregao_oc_pesquisa.aspx?chave='

    response = session.get(url_acesso, allow_redirects=True)
    cookie_1 = response.cookies.get_dict()
    response_1 = session.get(url)

    imagem = open('img.jpg', 'wb')
    imagem.write(response_1.content)

    ANTICAPTCHA_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" # KEY DA API QUEBRA DE CAPTCHA
    user_answer = ImageToTextTask.ImageToTextTask(anticaptcha_key = ANTICAPTCHA_KEY).captcha_handler(captcha_file='img.jpg')
    texto = user_answer['solution']['text']

    payload = {
        "__EVENTTARGET": "",
        "__EVENTARGUMENT": "",
        "__LASTFOCUS": "",
        "__VIEWSTATE": "viewstate",
        "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": "A4827007",
        "__EVENTVALIDATION": "",
        "ctl00$conteudo$Wuc_OC1$Wuc_filtroPesquisaOc1$c_ddlListaAtividadeGrupo": "1","ctl00$conteudo$Wuc_OC1$Wuc_filtroPesquisaOc1$c_ddlListaGrupoSituacao": "0",
        "ctl00$conteudo$Wuc_OC1$Wuc_filtroPesquisaOc1$cSecretaria": "",
        "ctl00$conteudo$Wuc_OC1$Wuc_filtroPesquisaOc1$cUgeCodigo": "",
        "ctl00$conteudo$Wuc_OC1$Wuc_filtroPesquisaOc1$cUgeDenominacao": "",
        "ctl00$conteudo$Wuc_OC1$Wuc_filtroPesquisaOc1$cMunicipio": "",
        "ctl00$conteudo$Wuc_OC1$Wuc_filtroPesquisaOc1$cTipoEdital": "0",
        "ctl00$conteudo$Wuc_OC1$Wuc_filtroPesquisaOc1$cEnteFederativo": "0",
        "ctl00$conteudo$Wuc_OC1$Wuc_filtroPesquisaOc1$cPartExclusiva": "0",
        "ctl00$conteudo$Wuc_OC1$Wuc_filtroPesquisaOc1$cAgrupamento": "0",
        "ctl00$conteudo$Wuc_OC1$Wuc_filtroPesquisaOc1$cNumeroOc": "",
        "ctl00$conteudo$Wuc_OC1$Wuc_filtroPesquisaOc1$cItemCodigo": "",
        "ctl00$conteudo$Wuc_OC1$Wuc_filtroPesquisaOc1$cItemDescricao": "",
        "ctl00$conteudo$Wuc_OC1$noRobot": texto,
        "ctl00$conteudo$Wuc_OC1$c_btnPesquisa": "Pesquisar"


response_2 = session.post(url_acesso, data=payload, cookies=cookie_1, headers={'Content-type': 'application/json'}, allow_redirects=True)
```

'''

Comment: A tecnologia usada no backend não importa muito (bom, importa no caso da resposta aceita, nessa que marquei como duplicada  - mas veja a minha resposta lá) - como você notou, os dados são carregados dinamicamente _depois_ do HTM estático ser carregado - então você vai ter que usar o `requests` do lado do Python para mandar um `post` copiando os dados que  o javascript da página envia, ou usar o selenium, em vez do requests - o selenium é executado em um browser, e ai todo o javascript dá página é executado  e você tem acesso a página completa.

Comment: Entendi cara, agradeço. O problema que estou tendo com o requests é não estou conseguindo trabalhar com os parâmetros "__EVENTVALIDATION" e "__VIEWSTATE" para enviar esse post, eles são extremamente grandes. Tens ideia se consigo por outro caminho além do selenium?

Comment: para o backend responder, você precisa envir os dados que ele espera. em vez de tentar copiar e colar esses dados no seu programa, você pode lê-los direto da página, depois de fazer um primeiro `get`. Ou salvar esses dados em um arquivo, e ler do arquivo para preencher os dados do post no Python.